# Get original data from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Customers, and a table Salesman, inside both a name column:

```
    Table Customers              Salesman Table
   --name--                           --name--
    Peter                              Charlie
    Vlado                              Clint
    Landon                             Tim
                                       Armand
```

if I use this query:

```
select a.name as CustomerName, b.name as SalesmanName from Customers a, Salesman b
```

then I get this:

```
CustomerName        SalesmanName
Peter                Charlie
Vlado                Charlie
Landon               Charlie
Peter                Clint
Vlado                Clint
Landon               Clint
Peter                Tim
Vlado                Tim
Landon               Tim
Peter                Armand
Vlado                Armand
Landon               Armand
```

But want to get is this:

```
CustomerName          SalesmanName
Peter                   Charlie
Vlado                    Clint
Landon                    Tim
                        Armand
```

What should I do? Is possible to get those columns exactly as they are in their tables using a query?

Comment: You just want to list the values in arbitrary pairs, but not repeat the values and list them regardless of which side has more values?

Comment: @HartCO exactly that's what I want

Comment: why do you need it this way instead of, say, as two queries and two separate results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate an arbitrary row number useful for joining the two:

```
;with cust AS (select name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS RN from Customers)
     ,sales AS (select name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS RN from Salesman)
select a.name as CustomerName
     , b.name as SalesmanName 
from cust a
FULL JOIN sales b
  ON a.RN = b.RN
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.RN,b.RN)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have primary key in your table, then you can pair these two column by using **ROW_NUMBER** and **FULL OUTER JOIN**. Lets say `CustomerId` and `SalesmanId` are the primary key of `Customers` and `Salesman` Table respectively. Now, Here is the query:-

```
SELECT 
     ISNULL(CS.Name, '') AS CustomerName,
     ISNULL(SM.Name, '') AS SalesmanName
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId) AS RN
    FROM Customers
) CS
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SalesmanId) AS RN
    FROM Salesman
) SM
ON SM.RN = CS.RN
```

Here is the Result

```
CustomerName          SalesmanName
   Peter                   Charlie
   Vlado                    Clint
   Landon                    Tim
                           Armand
```